# npm fails on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed the latest node.js msi on windows vista. I try to use npm but always get the error "failed to fetch from registry" in \lib\utils\npm-registry-client\get.js:139:12 with any package. I also used an http registry to disqualify an ssl issue with no avail. Also when I set http-proxy I see that nothing is actually sent.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the registry sites in your browser to rule out connection issues? I've always had good luck with the installer just working.

Comment: registry url is http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Sometimes yes. I am now able to sometimes use npm but it is unstable and not all modules work. Many time I need to install manually.

Comment: It has been a while since you posted this. Are you still having problems with the latest version?

Comment: @YaronNaveh Sounds like this has been worked out -- could you post an answer for this question and accept it?  Even if it's as simple as "upgrade to npm version x.x.x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded to a newer version (1.1.6) and it works great now!